# Is it possible to have physics affect fluid sim

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

What I want to simulate is ice cubes falling in a drink, I can use cube as col for physics for falling in the glass but I don't know if it's possible to have it affect the fluid as well, It falls but instead of bouncing towards the surface it goes down like it doesn't exist

Comment: Nope. It’s not implemented yet, though quite a few people have done some amazing tricks to try and make it look like it works.

Comment: It does affect the fluid sim, but it won't do so properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "affect the fluid"? You can make an ice cube fall into the drink and make it create a splash. For this to work, you need to make the cube a fluid collision object/obstacle. But you cannot make the ice cube swim on the drink AFAIK.

Comment: @TheLabCat I'll check it out on YouTube

Comment: @Blunder I know I can create splash but the cube float is what I wanted but Thanks I appreciate it

Comment: @lwswl I see, idk if Houdini does it but maybe I should try exporting sim from that to blender

Comment: @lwswl You can make a rigid body cube affect the fluid simulation (if you make it a fluid effector), but - quote from question "it goes down like it doesn't exist" - the fluid simulation will not affect the sinking of the cube in a rigid body simulation.